# While Loop and Split function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a use case where my SQL Script is having a variable with comma separated values.

```
whitelistURL = abc.com,xyz.com
```

I have to run insert command on all the values of the variable. Something like split with comma and run **insert on abc.com** and **insert on xyz.com**

Can someone please suggest the best way to do it. I am new to SQL.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Where are you getting the `whitelistURL` from? If possible, you should avoid using delimited strings and work with a table valued parameter instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @whitelistURL varchar(100) = 'abc.com,xyz.com,xyz.com,'
--set @whitelistURL = @whitelistURL + ','
;with cte as(
select charindex(',', @whitelistURL) [n], SUBSTRING(@whitelistURL, 1, 
charindex(',', @whitelistURL) - 1) [url]
union all
select charindex(',', @whitelistURL, n + 1), SUBSTRING(@whitelistURL, n + 1, charindex(',', @whitelistURL, n + 1) - n - 1) from cte
where charindex(',', @whitelistURL, n + 1) > 0
)

select [url] from cte
```

Only thing to note is that processed string should have delimeter (comma) also at the end, but if it doesn't, just append it, as I did in commented line.

Then insert statement becomes really easy:

```
insert into MY_TABLE (url) values
select url from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom split function. There are a lot of implementations of these functions on the web, here is an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split] (@Text nvarchar(MAX), @Delim char(1))
    RETURNS @Values TABLE (Value nvarchar(MAX))
AS
    BEGIN
        SET @Text = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Text))
        DECLARE @chrind int
        DECLARE @Piece nvarchar(100)
        SELECT @chrind = 1
        WHILE @chrind > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@Delim, @Text)

                IF @chrind > 0
                    SELECT @Piece = RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(@Text, @chrind - 1)))
                ELSE
                    SELECT @Piece = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Text))
                INSERT @Values(Value) VALUES(CAST(@Piece as varchar(100)))
                SELECT @Text = RIGHT(@Text, LEN(@Text) - @chrind)
                IF LEN(@Text) = 0 BREAK
            END
        RETURN
    END
```

This function takes two parameters:

1. the string to split (in your case `'abc.com,xyz.com,xyz.com,'`)
2. the separator (in your case `','`)

Now that you have your split function you can use it like this:

```
select [Value] from [dbo].[fn_Split]('abc.com,xyz.com',',')
```

This is the output of this command:

[image]

You can now combine this with an `insert` statement:

```
insert into YOUR_TABLE_NAME(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME) 
select [Value] from [dbo].[fn_Split]('abc.com,xyz.com',',')
```